# "IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String" when padding number with 0s?

Tags: java, regex, string-formatting

I had a perfectly working code yesterday, in the exact form of:

```
int lastRecord = 1;
String key = String.format("%08d", Integer.toString(lastRecord));
```

Which would pad it nicely to 00000001.

Now I kicked it up a notch with twoKeyChar getting a string from a table and lastRecord getting an int from a table.

As you can see the concept is essentially the same - I convert an int to a string and try to pad it with 0s; however, this time I get the following error:

```
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
```

The code is below:

```
String newPK = null;
String twoCharKey = getTwoCharKey(tablename);
if (twoCharKey != null) {
     int lastRecord = getLastRecord(tablename);
     lastRecord++;
     //The println below outputs the correct values: "RU" and 11. 
     System.out.println("twocharkey:"+twoCharKey+"record:"+lastRecord+"<");
     //Now just to make it RU00000011
     newPK = String.format("%08d", Integer.toString(lastRecord));
     newPK = twoCharKey.concat(newPK);
}
```

I feel like I must have typed something wrong, because there is no reason for it to break since the last time when it worked. Any help/hint is appreciated! Thank You!

Comment: In human form, that says "the format specifier `d` does not apply to String values".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You don't need the `Integer.toString()`:

```
 newPK = String.format("%08d", lastRecord);
```

`String.format()` will do the conversion and the padding.

Comment: I am going to go to my corner, feeling dumb... Nice catch! Thank You! Will accept answer in 10min when it lets me, heh.

Comment: Its not that you don't NEED to do the toString, but more like you CANNOT. The "d" in the first argument to String format expects a decimal integer. Hence the error.

Answer (score 3):

Very late to the party.

If you still are facing an issue to the `String.format();` code even after implementing accepted answer.

This did not work for me:

```
String.format("%08d", stringvariable);
```

Because of two reasons:

1. It will not work as `d` will expect for decimal point not string.
2. Use `%8d` instead of `%08d` as formatter did not work for me if I used this `%08d`

If you are using String based Variable with String data. Use this.

```
String.format("%8s", stringvariable);
```

Answer (score 3):

I our case with this problem it was do to java/kotlin conversion issue handling vargs because we had wrapped resources in a Kotlin file, where the missing trick was the flattern * operator

```
class LocalizedResources @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext context: Context
) {
    private val resources = LokaliseResources(context)

    fun getString(@StringRes resId: Int): String {
        return resources.getString(resId)
    }

    fun getString(@StringRes resId: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any?): String {
        return resources.getString(resId, *formatArgs)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me, It should be integer here 12 should be integer.

```
String.format("%04d", Integer.parseInt("12"));
```

output - 0012

Answer (score 1):

In Android you should replace `%1$s ... %d ... %.2f` with `%1$s ... %2$d ... %3$.2f`.

This way you will avoid `java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String` and `f != java.lang.String` exceptions.

Comment: I test this exact error with %1$d parsing int zero to it..

Comment: @MortenHolmgaard, sorry, what should I a answer? :)